# Call Angular web component method (CustomElement)

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

I have these two examples:

Example 1:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  options:any = {isOpen: false };

  logOptions() {
    console.log(this.options);
  }

}
```

Example 2:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  options:any = {isOpen: false };

  @Input() logOptions() {
    console.log(this.options);
  }

}
```

in html:

```
<app-root></app-root>

<script>
  document.querySelector('app-root').logOptions();
</script>
```

In Example 1 returns error: `document.querySelector(...).logOptions is not a function`

In Example 2 returns: `undefined`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish here? Telling us that would help us point you in the right direction. But regarding `Example 2`, you get `undefined` because you have declared a variable named `options` in the class, but you haven't assigned it to anything, so by default it's going to be `undefined` when you call a function that logs the value to the console.

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom element that I can later use it in a plain js app, for example a modal dialog with open and close methods

Comment: In example 2 I get undefined also when options is defined, I updated the example above

Comment: Not sure how/where you're trying to get `this.options` but here's an example where I call your `logOptions()` function in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook and have no problem getting the value: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ulovvd?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Did you look at the stackblitz? I think you need to provide more of your code, as it's unclear how you're actually invoking your function within the component if you're not using something like `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: I made an example on stackblitz, but it not seams tobe work on stackblitz, please try the same on localhost https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-web-component-custom-element

Comment: check the files index.html, app.module, app.compoenet

Comment: Your script tag under "app-root" runs first, by console logging you'd see that it runs before your component constructor, and even if you manage to wait for angular component resolution you would still not be able to access getOptions through the DOM. have you tried an event based solution? you could register custom events in your angular component and trigger them manually anywhere, even in your script tag with document.dispatchEvent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit late, but in case you still need this, there are couple of ways you could get it to work.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

    // @Input() << see comments below
    options: any = {isOpen: false };
    
    // This will NOT be available outside the component, in plain JS
    logOptions() {
        console.log(this.options);
    }

    // This will work ONLY if options is @Input()
    @Input()
    logOptions2() {
        console.log(this.options);
    }
    
    // This property will always provide correct data
    // Ideally a getter should not be @Input() though
    @Input()
    get logOptions3() {
        return this.options;
    }
}
```

You can access them in plain `JavaScript` code as

```js
const logComponentOptions = () => {
    const el = document.querySelector('app-root');
    // el.logOptions(); << Error
    el.logOptions2(); // works ONLY if options is @Input()
    console.log(el.logOptions3); // WORKS
    console.log(el.options); // if options is @Input()
}
```

1. So the `logOptions3` property can always be used to get the `options` from plain `javaScript` code. But semantically not correct (a `getter` as `@Input()`)
2. The first `logOptions()` method is not accessible from outside as it is NOT marked `@Input()`
3. The `logOptions2()` method is accessible but can only print correct value IF `options` is also marked `@Input()`
4. But if you mark the `options` property as `@Input()`, you can directly access that itself, rather than wrapping that in another method
5. Lastly, if you simply make `@Input() options = false`, you can also access it as a simple attribute from the `HTML` as well

```html
<app-root options="false"></app-root>
```

#### Update

If you want to pass data into the component, you can simply expose a `setter` property with `@Input`. Then you can set the value from outside the component, with `JavaScript`

```js
@Input()
public set myData(value: MyDataType) {
    // validation & logic if any
    this._myData = value;
}

// Then in JavaScript
const el = document.querySelector('app-root');
el.myData = {a: 10, b: true, c: 'my data object' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but logOptions3() with set or get anyway returns error `.logOptions3 is not a function`, I need to call method and pass some data to the component from javascript, this data can be type object like: `setOptions({isOpen: true})`

Comment: Notice that `logOptions3` is now a property (read-only, with `get`), so it IS NOT a functions. Just call it like a property `el.logOptions3` with no parentheses  For passing data into the component, i have updated my answer